# How to debug a CUDA program built by cmake in VIsual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, cuda, cuda-gdb

I'm trying to debug a test program with VS CODE, CMake in Ubuntu 20. I referred mainly to the CUDA debugger document: https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-code-edition/cuda-debugger/index.html.
However, I'm not sure about how to write a correct launch.json in a project based on CMake.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(cudaDebug CXX CUDA)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
add_executable(main main.cu)
```

Here is my launch.json generated by VS CODE

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CUDA C++: Launch",
            "type": "cuda-gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "main.cu"
        },
        {
            "name": "CUDA C++: Attach",
            "type": "cuda-gdb",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I press F5 to start debugging, an error information poped up:

```
main.cu: 346262241346234211351202243344270252346226207344273266346210226347233256345275225.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to change the following line:

```
         "program": "main.cu"
```

to

```
         "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}"
```

and select the executable in VSCode (usually on the bottom row where you can also select build targets).

Have also a look here:

https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/debugging.html

Answer (score 2):

you can try to update your cmake version to higher than 3.10, which no longer need to use `find_package(CUDA)`
here is one template for vscode and cmake to use cuda-gdb
`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(your_project_name CUDA CXX C)  # enable cuda language
set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} "-g -G")  # enable cuda-gdb

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE your_source_files)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

`tasks.json`

```json
{
    "options": {
       "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"  
    },
    "tasks": [
       {
          "label": "cmake",  
          "command":"cmake",  
          "args": ["-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug", ".."]  
       },
       {
          "label": "make",  
          "command":"make",  
       },
       {
          "label": "cmake build", 
          "dependsOn":[  
             "cmake",
             "make"
          ],
       }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
 }
```

`launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CUDA C++: Launch",
            "type": "cuda-gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/your_executable_file",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "cmake build"
        }
     ]
}
```

wish it could help you :)